# IF all cells in a range are the same, excluding blank cells

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a table to calculate the price of a project, where one column is the description of an element of the project followed by a column for its unit (usually hours), the price per unit, number of units, and the final price,
sort of like this:

[image]

My question really only involves the highlighted cells. Im making a template, and I add elements to the table as I go along, so some rows are left blank, but I want the total number of hours to be displayed in D7 (easy enough, =SUM(D2:D6)), but my problem is that some of the elements aren't written per hour (eg. row 4), so I want the total to only show up if all the values are for hours. Essentially:

IF **all values in row B are "Hours"**, then **sum of row D**, else **""**)

I guess in short, is there a formula I can use that would return *TRUE* if all the values in a range are the same, **excluding** blank cells?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try building an Array formula (Ctrl+Shift+Enter), something along the lines of `SUM(IF(Unit Range = "Hours", Quantity, 0))`. Let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: Well, `=COUNTIFS(B2:B6,"<>Hours",B2:B6,"*")=0` would do just what you ask. @JustynaMK, are you trying to replicate `SUMIF`? =)

Comment: @JvdV hah I wouldn't dare! :) I guess I rushed too much with the answer and, instead of just showing `TRUE` or `FALSE` as requested, I added all values which are hours... this calls for another coffee.

Comment: @JvdV Hi, yeah I'm looking for something like 'SUMIF' except I want to leave the cell blank if not all the elements are calculated in hours. Ill try both of your suggestions and let you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your last comment, you can try:

[image]
[image]

Formula in `D7`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B2:B6,"<>Hours",B2:B6,"*")=0,SUM(D2:D6),"")
```

Comment: Thanks this seems to work! But I've got one other curveball to throw, if you can think of a solution.
In an effort to make the process of using this table easy to use, when I type in an element in column A, the rest of the information for that row is filled in on its own. I can't explain it all in a comment, but the gist of it is the cells in column B contain formulas `IFERROR(VLOOKUP('Backend'!$A1, 'Backend'!$A$1:$F$99, 2, FALSE), "")` not the actual text itself, so the formula doesn't work.

Comment: I don't see why the formula won't work. Even on output through formulas it should still do its job.

Comment: Hmmm, then I've got no idea what the problem is. The solution works if I manually write "Hours" into column B, but not when they're formulas... Here's the real table, maybe I've missed something [link](https://imgur.com/M58IZ2V)

Comment: Maybe there are leading or trailing zeros? You can counter that with: `=IF(COUNTIFS(B2:B6,"<>*Hours*",B2:B6,"*")=0,SUM(D2:D6),"")`, @AnžeOberčMrzel

Comment: Unsure, but I checked to see what value `COUNTIFS(B2:B6,"<>*Hours*",B2:B6,"*")` returns. Figured out it returns the number of cells in the range that are NOT **"Hours"**, so ive just reworked that part of the formula to be `COUNTIFS(B2:B6,"<>*Hours*",B2:B6,"*")-COUNTBLANK(B2:B6)=0` which seems to work (don't know if there's a simpler way to write it, but that's not super important), So thanks for all the help :)